# For loop bug in c#

Tags: c#

I am doing an assignment that consists of having a class and the program must take the first name, last name, and GPA but the id is generated from the loop. A student structure must be created and two functions one for taking the GPA corresponding to the id and another to print the list of students and the main that should be combining. The initial GPA of each student is 0 until updated by the function. The issue is that the function that updates the GPA is bugging after finishing all students it starts repeating for id 0 even though there's no id 0. That's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_1
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct student {
            public int id;
            public String fName, lName;
            public float gpa;
        };

        public static void printList(student[] std) {
            for (int i = 0; i < std.Length; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine("Student #" + (i + 1) + " :");
                Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + std[i].fName);
                Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + std[i].lName);
                Console.WriteLine("ID: " + std[i].id);
                Console.WriteLine("GPA: " + std[i].gpa);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public static void gpa(student[] std) {
            for (int i = 0; i < std.Length; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter GPA for ID: " + std[i].id);

                do
                {
                    std[i].gpa = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                } while (std[i].gpa < 0 || std[i].gpa > 4);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student[] std = new student[30];
            for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the first name of student " + (n + 1));
                std[n].fName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the last name of student " + (n + 1));
                std[n].lName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                std[n].id = n + 1;
                std[n].gpa = 0;
            }
            gpa(std);
            printList(std);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you declare array with size 30 if you have only 5 students?

Comment: It's time to learn how to use the debugger. If you step through the code and examine the variables, you can see where it doesn't do what you expect and discover why.

Comment: Probably because student is a struct. Did you get compiler warnings? Make it a class and "new" it before you fill it

Comment: Yep, you are seeing ID of 0 because you are declaring an array of 30 students and only populating 5 of them.  The ID of the remaining 25 is 0 because the default value of an integer is 0, and a struct doesn't default itself to null like a class does.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing he would still have issues if he made it a class.  It would just actually blow up instead of giving misleading output.

Comment: A classic reason to forget arrays and use `List<T>`

Comment: @Steve for a problem like this arrays are fine.  You just have to be conscious of how you are declaring and using them.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your main function to something like this, which will only define an array for the exact number of students you need, note the addition of "int numStudents = 5;" and the use of the numStudents variable in the declaration of std and break condition of the for loop:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numStudents = 5;
        student[] std = new student[numStudents];
        for (int n = 0; n < numStudents ; n++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first name of student " + (n + 1));
            std[n].fName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the last name of student " + (n + 1));
            std[n].lName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            std[n].id = n + 1;
            std[n].gpa = 0;
        }
        gpa(std);
        printList(std);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using List instead of arrays. When you declare an array of structs for 30 students, They are allocated on memory even if you didn't set values.
Use any ICollections instead such as a List.

A collection will store only added entities over Add() method.

```
        public struct student
        {
            public int id;
            public String fName, lName;
            public float gpa;
        };

        public static void printList(List<student> stds)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stds.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Student #" + (i + 1) + " :");
                Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + stds[i].fName);
                Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + stds[i].lName);
                Console.WriteLine("ID: " + stds[i].id);
                Console.WriteLine("GPA: " + stds[i].gpa);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public static void gpa(List<student> stds)
        {
            //Instead of length, Use count in a collection
            for (int i = 0; i < stds.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = stds[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Enter GPA for ID: " + item.id);
                item.gpa = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instead of an array, Declare studets as a list (collection)
            List<student> stds = new List<student>();

            for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
            {
                //Create a student everytime you loop
                var std = new student();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the first name of student " + (n + 1));
                std.fName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the last name of student " + (n + 1));
                std.lName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                std.id = n + 1;
                std.gpa = 0;

                //And add it to our list
                stds.Add(std);
            }
            gpa(stds);
            printList(stds);
        }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Students are usually forbidden to use collections. They spend four years learning the wrong ways to do everything, then have to unlearn it all when they get into the real world.

Comment: I used your way but when I run it doesn't it says that the program exited with code 0 is there something wrong with the compiler or the code? I'm using visual studio

Comment: Exactly @KevinKrumwiede. This is one of the sad truth. I think this is because arrays are the basics for them to understand the fundamentals. Collections comes in during the applications getting sophisticated. I think so

Comment: @michelpro332 I was able to run it and get the results. Can you explain a bit more on the issue, so we can troubleshoot

Comment: I tried lists but it didn't work and we didn't learn it in class anyways. The problem is that when the program is taking the GPA corresponding to each id when it finishes the fifth it starts saying Enter for id 0 over and over and at last it exits and says exited with code 0

Comment: Are you sure you copied the entire code? I can easily run it without this issue